# Add attributes to React element from string

Tags: reactjs

My CMS outputs a string of data attributes to add to an element
I wanted to know how I can add the string of attributes to an element in React

This sample code does not appear to work.

```
function HelloWorld(props) {
  const fromCMS = `data-target="h1" data-content="Hello World"`;
  return (
    <h1 {fromCMS}>{props.content}</h1>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one.

```
const fromCms = {"data-target": "h1", "data-content": "Hello World"}
...
<h1 {...fromCMS}>
```

Comment: Cannot change the string that's output from CMS

Comment: Use regular expression to change it to the JSON string and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setAttribute() method
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

you must separate the strings to add the atributes